# p: remoteCommand does not work in the web browser on iphone devices

Tags: ios, ajax, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

In my project where I use jsf primefaces, I use p: remote command to update the panel in java code. 
 When I entered the mobile website, I wrote code to be sensitive to the component when the orientation of the device changes. When I enter my website from android devices it is working . But it doesn't work when I go to my website on ios devices.

**xhtml Code**

```
<h:form id="chartForm">
<h:panelGrid id="hoddChartPanelId" columns="1">
<p:remoteCommand id="rcChangeOrientationDevice"
name="rcChangeOrientationDevice"
actionListener="#{rampBean.changeOrientationHoddChart}"
process="@this"
partialSubmit="true"
update=":growl,:chartForm:hoddChartPanelId"
onstart="setStatusDialogValue(false);"
onsuccess="setStatusDialogValue(true);"/>

<p:panel id="hoddChartPanel" styleClass="hodd-chart-panel"
header="#{messageMap['HODD_CHART_WITH_DEADLOAD_INFO']} #{rampBean.hoddChartPanelTitle}" rendered="#{hoddChartWithDeadloadInfoBean.hoddChartWithDeadloadInfo.hoddChart!=null}">
<div class="hoddChart-image">
<p:graphicImage id="hoddChartImage" 
value="#{hoddChartWithDeadloadInfoBean.hoddChartWithDeadloadInfo.hoddChart}"
style="cursor:zoom-in; border-style:outset; border-color:black; border-width:3px; " />
```

------------Editted:--------

```
<h:outputScript>
function findOrientation(){
 window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
var orientation = screen.orientation.type;
rcChangeOrientationDevice([{name: 'orientation', value: orientation}]);
}, false);
}
</h:outputScript>
```

**Bean Java Code**

```
public void changeOrientationHoddChart() {
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
 Map<String,String> params = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
        String orientation = params.get("orientation");
        if("portrait-primary".equals(orientation)){
            hoddChartInputData.setVertical(true);
        }else {
            hoddChartInputData.setVertical(false);
        }
    }
```

When I enter my website from the computer and look at the chrome debugging mode, it appears and worked on the panel. It does not work on mobile devices.

Comment: Who is calling `rcChangeOrientationDevice()`? Who sets the parameter 'orientation'?

Comment: I get the orientation with the javascript code.

Comment: Why exactly is this a JSF problem? Are you saying that the logic in your `findOrientation()` works fine? Have you already replaced `rcChangeOrientationDevice([{name: 'orientation', value: orientation}]);` by e.g. `console.log("bla");` merely to logically exclude the one and other? It's difficult to nail down the cause of the problem because this is not a [mcve] at all.